# Cover this disc

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Can you place five discs of radius 1, such that they fully cover a disc of radius 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is proof that it is

> not possible.
>
>  You can't even just cover the boundary of the $R=2$ disc with five unit discs. If the unit disc covers a section of the boundary, the two extremal points are at most two units apart (the diameter of the unit disc). A section of the boundary stretching for two units is exactly $1/6$ of the whole boundary (think of an inscribed regular hexagon, which will have side lengths equal to the radius), so it takes at least 6 discs to cover the boundary alone, and then you still haven't covered the centre of the disc. Therefore it takes at least $7$ unit discs to cover a disc of radius $2$.

Comment: This is a better answer for this question +1

Comment: Agreed. +1 from me too

Comment: Thank you, great answer.

Answer (score 4):

> No

> The maximum radius that can be covered is 1.641+.
>  See https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovcir/

Comment: Correct and thanks for the reference. I found this as one of Carnival games called "cover the spot": https://youtu.be/JZkXmf7sPGg